How to stop a certain window of an app to always be on top
After an upgrade of my system to Ubuntu 24.04 I am observing a new behavior whose cause I yet fail to understand, and for which I have not found a satisfactory solution. Which is that once I switch from one active window to another one belonging to a second app, a certain window of the first app will be put in the foreground.
For example, I have two windows of evince open, and keep them on the left side of my screen. One of them displays a digitalised manuscript, the other one a draft edition/translation of the text contained in that manuscript. On the right hand side of the screen I have a terminal running with several tabs, the main ones of which is a vim session in which I edit a tex file of my draft, and another one running latexmk -pvc of that file, i.e. permanently updating the pdf of my draft whenever I change anything in the latex source. Now before the upgrade I used to be in control which window of evince I would see on the left side, either the manuscript, or my draft, but now, whenever I switch from the active evince-window to the terminal window, a certain window of evince gets activated, over which I seem to have no control. If this window happens to be the pdf of my draft, then, assuming I have on the left side of the screen the pdf of the manuscript in the foreground, the I switch to the vim-session in my terminal on the right side of the screen in order to transcribe from the manuscript, this is not possible anymore, as once I switch from evince to the terminal as active window, it keeps bringing my edition to the front, and I don't see the manuscript. Well, I can do things like keeping the manuscript always on top, or pushing it to another workspace, with my terminal visible on all workspaces, but this is just a workaround, and I would prefer to get the old behavior back, that whatever window of evince was in the foreground on the left side of the screen remains there even if I switch to another app on the right side of the screen, as was the case before the upgrade. How do I get that behavior back?
I assume this is a gnome question, but if it is something else, please feel free to edit my question adding the appropriate tags.

You seem to have answered your own question. Consider converting your edit into an answer that will benefit future folks with similar questions.

It seems this behavior is caused by Enhanced Tiling und Settings -> Ubuntu Desktop, and if I disable it, I get the old behavior back. Probably I should read up on the Enhanced Tiling feature and see what I miss by disabling it, and if there's a better way of achieving control over the windows in the foreground.
